# window.opener is undefined when the url is opened in same window

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, javascript-objects

In our Angulajs controller, we are trying to open an external URL in the same window (this is a requirement to open the  the URL in same browser, instead of creating a popup), using below line:

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

when we try to get the instance of parent window (to access the controller methods) we always get `window.opener` as `undefined`. Can you please let me know what might be the reason ?

Same behavior can be seen if we use `window.location.href="www.youraddress.com"`

Please let me know what are we missing here ?

Comment: I believe that's intended. You only have a value on your `window.opener` if you open a link in a new tab or window.

Comment: If the window is in a different domain, you are not going to be able to reference the opener. If the window replaces the same window, what is there to reference since you just destroyed that page? It is like a whiteboard, you erased it and replaced the board with new content.

Comment: @epascarello: But even more so: You've taken the whiteboard out and thrown it in the bin, and replaced it with a *new* whiteboard in the same place. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the page in the same window, the old window object gets destroyed. There's no longer an object for `window.opener` to refer to. You can only keep referring to it if the window still exists. Even if you could, you would be denied access to its content, as you're loading an external URL into it and thus the Same Origin Policy comes into play. Even if it weren't for the SOP, all of the content that used to be in that window (including the JavaScript environment it used to have) would have been destroyed.

Any code or data you intend to keep using will need to be in the window where you're trying to use `window.opener` (or in another related window that isn't being replaced).

Comment: OK, that makes sense to me. But, in that case, how to can I get access to the controller methods ? I am even ready to use window.location.href, but did not found a way to call the controller methods.

Comment: @SKJ: You can't, nothing that was in that window exists anymore. You'll need to put anything you intend to keep using in the window where you're trying to use `window.opener`.